# jquery UI tooltip - not showing on the top of element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position, tooltip

Please check my code at this [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tKwKX/)

I want my tooltip to show on top of the element.
what am I doing wrong?

I also didn't find any usable info about position property in the jquery UI documentation for tooltips
what does my and at means... I copied the code from their demos

Answer (score 9):

You should set position 'my' to 'bottom-(distance of bottom)
Check this [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tKwKX/10/)

Comment: Thanks... what do this terms mean... my and at?
anyway. why did I loose the animation in your example?

Comment: 'my' is:
position: {
  **my:** "center bottom-50",
  at: "center top"
},
You loose the animation, because i changed the tooltip position but not change the beginning of the animation, see here [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tKwKX/14/). in this line `ui.tooltip.animate({ top: ui.tooltip.position().top + 10 }, "fast"`

Comment: you can add the animation back by changing the `show` option to: `{
                effect: "slideDown",
                delay: 250
            }`

Comment: lol.. ahahah 
see here [jQuery UI position options](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position)

Comment: no, than it will do completly opposite of what I need. http://jsfiddle.net/QFApL/24/ here is almost perfect

Comment: Also, for position options, see the utility documentation for position: [jQueryUI Position Utility](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch: I have checked and messed around a nit, but still, nothing is explained... what my represents and what at represents

Comment: I edited my answer above to explain... not enough characters to do so here.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, you want the tooltip text to completely cover the image it's meant to tooltip?

Unfortunately that's not possible with tooltip.  The reason being, tooltip is only valid while the mouse is "over" the element the tooltip is initiated on.  The moment your tooltip covers that element, your mouse is then over the tooltip, instead of the selected element, which would trigger the close event for the tooltip.

If the end result is more important than the how, you could set both the `open` and `close` events for the tooltip to `click` instead of their defaults, then position accordingly.

**Edit** (to explain `at` and `my`:

`my` and `at` are sort of like a dynamic x,y coordinate system to help you align your elements, except each one is an x,y in and of itself.  They both allow you to set reference points within 2 objects that have a relationship to each other, in this case being the tooltip (`my`), and the object the tooltip is instantiated on (`at`).

`my` in your case is the tooltip that pops up, and `at` is the image that when mousein event is triggered on, causes the tooltip to instantiate.  Each one of these options, takes a flat string, or a relative string-position, to determine the 2 objects relationship (in position of the DOM) to each other.  So, if you want the top center of the tooltip to align with the absolute center of the image, regardless of where they appear in the DOM, you would set the following:

```
position: {
            my: "center top",
            at: "center center"
        }
```

You can gain further control by offsetting either/both `my` and `at` by combining a pixel value or % value.

```
position: {
            my: "center+10 top+50",
            at: "center+5 center+25"
        }
```

Comment: no, I just want my tooltip to sho on the TOP of my element. plus s simple animation like here: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-animation (last link, instead of showing at the bottom, to show at the top)

Comment: In that case, Bruno's got you covered.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to give simple answer to future searcher who couldn't get his mind around this term.. The definition is.. my is my selector.. like 'my' image..

```
$('img').tooltip();
```

Meanwhile at is where the tooltip should appear 'at'

For example:

```
$('img').tooltip({ position: { my: "right center", at: "left center" } });
```

Here, we have chose the 'my' image to be at the right, vertically centered.. and the tooltip to be appear 'at' the left relative to image and vertically centered as well..